# Fontawesome styles are not applied

Tags: html, css, font-face, font-awesome

I have problem, I am trying to get the same result as in the example (Fontawesom) https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/

I want to implement

**Fixed Width Icons**

I have downloaded FontAwesome package in my folder and add link in head        I have also tried CDN like but the same result. Icons are showed but styles are not applied as in the example.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSJiJ.jpg

Here is my result

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

And list

```
 <div class="list-group">
           <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Home</a>
           <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-book fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Library</a>
           <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Applications</a>
           <a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw"></i>&nbsp; Settings</a>
        </div>
```

Please help, what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Please include a full but minimal repro in the question.

Comment: yes some code please

Comment: Please see my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styles are not the same because you have the fontawesoms icons in an `anchor` tag, so the icons are inheriting the anchors styles. Just override those styles, like:

```
.list-group-item{
     color: #000; /* black */
     text-decoration: none; /* remove the underline */
     display: block; /* to make the anchors take full width */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well to achieve this you have to update your CSS accordingly. change color and size of your font as per your requirement.